# php cURL LOGIN does not work

Tags: php, curl, authentication, authorization

Now I am trying to login to my account using PHP and CURL, but still I am not sure why is not working.

The page I'm trying to login to is: http://lardi-trans.com/index.jsp
After the execution of the script, I get the same page without authorization.
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php


$url = "http://lardi-trans.com/log/index.jsp";
$referer = "http://lardi-trans.com/index.jsp";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0";
$post = "action=/log/login.jsp&log=MYLOGIN&passwd=MYPASSWORD&enter=enter&onlog=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8";
$header [] = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header [] = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";
$header [] = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
$header [] = "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
$user_cookie = "cookies.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "identity");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $page;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your $url variable to the value of the login form's action - http://lardi-trans.com/log/login.jsp

Comment: Thanks.
Form doesn't contains Action.
After i changed it page is not displayed, only the header.

I changed to `$post = "action=http://lardi-trans.com/log/login.jsp&log=MYLOGIN&passwd=MYPASS&enter=enter&onlog=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8";`

Comment: The form does contain action:
<form action="/log/login.jsp" method="post">
........                 </form>

Comment: I tried as Eugene wrote, but page is not displayed, only the header.
`$post = "action=/log/login.jsp&log=MYLOGIN&passwd=MYPASS&enter=ent‌​er&onlog=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8";`

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I just started learning php and error may be simple, but I want to understand how it works.

Comment: Maybe that page makes a redirect after log in. Start by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to your code (in case the server sends redirect with HTTP Header). If not, check the server's response for JS or meta tag redirect.

Comment: followlocation didn't help. HttpFox displays POST redirect to http://lardi-trans.com/log/login.jsp --> then GET redirect to /log/user.php --> and to /log/index.jsp.

Will it help?